# Cython: unable to assign to 2d vector

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have the following:

```
# distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def foo():
    cdef vector[vector[int]] matrix 
    matrix.reserve(100);
    matrix[0] = [1,2,3]
    print(matrix)
foo()
```

It prints out an empty list; I expected it to print out a vector with the first element being `[1,2,3]`.

Setup.py script:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='myfile',
    ext_modules=cythonize("my_file.pyx"),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

How do  I fix this?

Comment: @bhristov what specifically are you asking for? This compiles and runs fine on my machine. I have edited and added the setup.py script if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `matrix.resize(100)` and not `matrix.reserve(100)`. `std::vector<>::reserve` doesn't change the size of the vector - it only reserves the memory so no further (multiple) reallocations need to happen:

```
%%cython
...
matrix.reserve(100)
print(matrix.size())  # prints 0
matrix.resize(100)
print(matrix.size())  # prints 100
...
```

Right now `matrix[0] = [1,2,3]` is undefined behavior (the size is `0` - there are no elements) and you are unlucky it doesn't crash due to out of range access.